# Django User Posts filter by year

Tags: python, django

In Django I needed user Posts  filter by year,  so I did the following in  views:
Views:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Count
from .models import Book

def about (request):
    model = Book
    context = {
        
        'books': Book.objects.values('author')
        .filter(date_posted__year=2019)
        .annotate(total_books = Count('author'))             
    }
```

In the HTML

```
books.author.id
books.author
books.total_books
```

It worked,  it shows the total but instead of printing de Author username,  it prints the Author ID,  and the author ID is blank.
Django Version 3.0.8

This is the complete HTML:

```
{% block content %}

<div class="container">   
        <div class="w-50">
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">User ID</th>
                        <th scope="col">Username </th>
                        <th scope="col">Total Books</th>           
                    </tr>
                </thead>
             
            {% for books in books %}
                
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <ul>
                        <td> {{ books.author }}</td>
                        <td> {{ books.author }} </td>
                        <td>{{ books.total_qcreports}}</td>
                        </ul>  
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

            {% endfor %}
            </table>           
        </div> 
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is how it shows in browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcpMd.png)

Comment: Since `books.author` shows the author's username, I suspect that `author` is a string rather than an object, which won't have an `id` column. Please include more, say, your `views`?

Comment: use `Book.objects.values('author__username').filter(date_posted__year=2019)
        .annotate(total_books = Count('author'))`

Comment: I think the question is kind of ambiguous, as the title read "filter posts by year" but the actual problem is that `books.author.id` is not showing up... @Rocio Zanbrabi Romo can you please elaborate on your question?

Comment: Please show your html template

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the replies. I've updated and included full HTML and Models.  I want to filter by year the total books for each user.   
I tried suhailvs code but username still not showing.

Answer (score 0):

```
context = {
        
        'books': Book.objects.values('author','author__username')
        .filter(date_posted__year=2019)
        .annotate(total_books = Count('author'))             
    }
```

**HTML Template**

```
{{book.author}}
{{book.author__username}}
{{book.total_book}}
```

Comment: Okay, you tried my previous answer?  This will work with `values` also

Comment: Pruthvi Barot,  you are right,  the option with values worked better!!